# PHPUnit + Maven for PHP - setUpBeforeClass() not called

Tags: maven-2, phpunit, maven-for-php

When running the "mvn test" command, the PHPUnit tests are run.
The problem I have is that the setUpBeforeClass() method within a test class is not called when running the tests from maven.
Does anybody know the problem? I use the last version of PHPUnit (3.3.9) available on repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @khmarbaise, support of `setUpBeforeClass()` has been added in PHPUnit 3.4+ (see [Ticket #814](http://www.phpunit.de/ticket/814)) and my understanding is that you would just have to **install PHPUnit 3.4+ from PEAR** to get it used by Maven. Follow [the install instructions](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html).

Comment: Thank you, Pascal. The problem is I can't get the 3.4.12 (the last version) working with maven. I tried to manually install a zip/jar file in the local repository as they say on the php-maven.org/add3partylibs.html but it seems not to work.
When running "mvn install" it gives me a build error wothout any description.

[INFO] php.out: PHPUnit 3.4.12 by Sebastian Bergmann.
[INFO] php.out: Time: 1 second, Memory: 4.25Mb
[INFO] php.out: OK (2 tests, 2 assertions)
[ERROR] Testcase: querytest.php fails.
[ERROR] See log: C:\un/querytest.txt
[INFO]
PHPUnit 3.4.12 by Sebastian Bergmann...

Any ideas?

Comment: querytest.txt content:

PHPUnit 3.4.12 by Sebastian Bergmann...Time: 1 second, Memory: 4.25MbOK (2 tests, 2 assertions)

Comment: @Softy I may be wrong but I don't thing that adding PHPUnit to your local repository does change something. I understood that phpunit is an executable, installing a newer version from PEAR will make you use the newer version. Does your current version of phpunit work outside Maven? Can you test this?

Comment: @Pascal I do have the last version (3.4.12) in place and working, I used it to test my tests before trying it with maven. So it is installed on my system. But if I don't put a dependency in the pom.xml to the phpunit it doesn't see it.

Comment: @Softy Ok, forget what I said then. So to summarize: phpunit 3.4.12 works on the command line, you can run your test with it, but it doesn't work under Maven. Is that correct? Can you try to call `mvn -X -e` to see if you get more information about the problem?

Comment: I get something like this: (extract from huge output) - is there any way I can send you the whole output?
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException:
PHPUnit 3.4.12 by Sebastian Bergmann...Time: 1 second, Memory: 4.25MbOK (2 tests, 2 assertions) in

        at org.phpmaven.plugin.build.PhpUnitCompile.executePhpFile(PhpUnitCompile.java:251)
.........
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.phpmaven.plugin.build.PhpCompileException:

Comment: @Softy post the output on a paster like http://pastie.org and put the link here as comment.

Comment: @Pascal Thank you! I've tried several other versions of PHPUnit (3.4.0/3.4.2/3.4.10) and I put here the error: http://pastie.org/948377 (3.4.0). Hope you can see something in there.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the docs of [phpunit](http://www.phpunit.de) correct there is no setUpBeforeClass() for the 3.3.9 release only in PHPUnit 3.4.X Release i found such method.

Comment: Thank you. Then is there any method to use the PHPUnit 3.4.X with Maven for PHP? Any ideas? I tried to manually install a zip/jar file in the local repository as they say on the http://www.php-maven.org/add3partylibs.html but it seems not to work...

Comment: It seems that maven sees the PHPUnit 3.4.12 version, runs it, but I get an error.

        at org.phpmaven.plugin.build.PhpUnitCompile.executePhpFile(PhpUnitCompile.java:241)
        ... 28 more
[DEBUG] --- Compiling has finished.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR

Caused by: org.phpmaven.plugin.build.PhpCompileException:

AND

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: